# Algebra of polynomials.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am going through the book Linear Algebra by Hoffman & Kunze and i'm having trouble understanding the sequence of reasoning in the book which follows (mostly paraphrased). I hoping for some clarifications on the question which i've put in the end.

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field and $S$ the set of non-negative integers. The set of all functions from $S$ into $\mathbb{F}$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{F}$, denoted by $\mathbb{F}^\infty$. Moreover, $\mathbb{F}^\infty$ forms a commutative algebra over $\mathbb{F}$.

We denote some vectors in the following way:
$$1 = (1,0,0, \dots) \\ x = (0,1,0, \dots) \\ x^2 = (0,0,1, \dots)$$

The subspace spanned by the vectors $1,x,x^2, \dots$ is denoted by $\mathbb{F}[x]$ and an element of $\mathbb{F}[x]$ is called a polynomial over $\mathbb{F}$.

My question is: Is $\mathbb{F}[x]$ a proper subspace of $\mathbb{F}^\infty$ ? I am unable to see why the vectors $1,x,x^2, \dots$ do not span $\mathbb{F}^\infty$. If there is indeed no difference, is the distinction made only to facilitate a thorough definition of a polynomial?

Comment: $1+x+x^2+...$ or $(1,1,1,...)$ is not in $F[x]$. Linear combinations are finite sums only.

Comment: Consider the map $n\mapsto 1$ for every $n$, i.e. $(1,1,1,\ldots)$. This is not a polynomial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There *is* a difference. What they denote $\mathbb F^\infty$ is usually denoted $\mathbb F^\mathbf{N}$: it is the set of all sequences of elements of $\mathbb F$.

Polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb F$ is usually defined as the set of all such sequences with finite support, i.e. the set of all sequences  with all terms $0$, except a finite number of them. It is usuually denoted $\mathbb F^{(\mathbf N)}$. Endowed with term-wise addition and an *ad hoc* multiplication, it is denoted $\mathbb F[x]$.

Indeed, $1$, $x$, $x^2$, &c., have a finite support and a sequence:
$$(a_0, a_1,\dots, a_n,0,\dots,0,\dots),\enspace\text{with }\;a_n\ne 0,$$
is the same as $$a_0(1,0,\dots,0,\dots)+a_1(0,1,0,\dots, 0,\dots)+\dots+a_n (0,0,\dots,0,1,0,\dots,0,\dots),$$
so it is usually denoted 
$$a_0+a_1x+\dots+a_nx^n.$$

*Note*:

The vector space $\mathbb F^{\mathbf{N}}$, endowed  with the *Cauchy product* (inspired by the product of polynomials) is another $\mathbb F$-algebra, which is called the *ring of formal power series* with coefficients in $\mathbb F$.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{F}[x]$ is the collection of all *finite* linear combinations of powers of $x$ - so, for example, it includes $1 + x = (1,1,0,0,\ldots)$ and $x^2 + x^3 = (0,0,1,1,0,0,\ldots)$. But, for example, $(1, 1, 1, 1, \ldots)$ is not a finite linear combination - it would best be written $1 + x + x^2 + \cdots$.

In other words, $\mathbb{F}^{\infty}$ is the set of all functions. $\mathbb{F}[x]$ is the set of all functions *with finite support* - that is, the set of all functions that are nonzero in only finitely many places.

Comment: Thanks. The fact that linear combinations are finite is the key fact that I missed.